# Problem with Type casting while setting edit mode for radgrid

Tags: asp.net, type-conversion, radgrid, telerik-grid

I have The following code to set the edit mode for Radgrid based on condition but i am getting error saying cannot implcitly convert bool to telerik.web.ui.grideditmode

My Code is

```
bool EditPrivilege = this.Privilige.CanModify;
 this.FileAdminRadGrid.MasterTableView.EditMode = EditPrivilege
```

Comment: [GridEditMode Enumeration](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/t_telerik_web_ui_grideditmode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Error says clearly what is wrong. EditMode is not of type bool. But You try to assign EditPrivilege of type bool to it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , my actual intention is prevent the rowdouble click editing property of radgrid based on the user permission whether its true or false

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to define EditPrivilege as a boolean when it should be of the Telerik type EditMode/Privilige.

Have you tried (something like):

`Privilige EditPrivilege = this.Privilige.CanModify;  this.FileAdminRadGrid.MasterTableView.EditMode = EditPrivilege`